# How do you use an executor to resolve a Future in rust?

Tags: rust

This code panics:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::Future;
use futures::future;
use futures::sync::oneshot::{channel, Canceled};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn maybe_oneday() -> Box<Future<Item = i32, Error = Canceled>> {
    let (s, r) = channel::<i32>();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        let _ = s.send(100);
    });
    return Box::new(r);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = maybe_oneday();
    let mut wrapper = foo.then(|x| {
        match x {
            Ok(v) => {
                println!("GOT: {:?}", v);
                future::ok::<i32, Canceled>(v)
            },
            Err(y) => {
                println!("Err: {:?}", y);
               future::err::<i32, Canceled>(y)
            }
        }
    });

    // wrapper.wait() <-- Works, but blocks
    let _ = wrapper.poll(); // <-- Panics
}
```

With:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'no Task is currently running', /checkout/src/libcore/option.rs:891:5
```

Presumably I have to use some kind of executor to delegate the task resolution to; but how?

The documentation refers to `my_executor`, but [there appear to be no implementations of this trait](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/future/trait.Executor.html#implementors), and the [find out more about executors](https://tokio.rs/docs/going-deeper-futures/tasks/) link is broken?

Where do I get an executor from?

Comment: It might help if you expand on why you want to use `.poll` instead of blocking with `.wait`. Generally the idea with a future would be to avoid polling constantly to see if it is done.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Well, how do you do that without `poll`? `thread::spawn(|| { x.wait(); })`? I thought this was the problem an executor was supposed to solve. I'm happy to do it another way if there's some other way of doing it. All I want is not to block the current thread.

Comment: I thought I read something recently about an executor that multiplexes all the tasks assigned to it over a single thread, but I can't find it now?

Comment: Whatever code that needs the value `v` can be triggered from _inside_ your `.then` callback for instance. Instead of doing `.poll` to try to get the value, you can do `.wait` and then right where you have `println!("GOT: {:?}", v);`, just do whatever operation you wanted to do with `v` there.

Comment: I don't really understand how what you're suggesting avoids blocking the current thread. Could you post an actual example of how this would work? (If I wanted to block the main thread, I would just use a synchronous function; how is what you're suggesting any different to that?)

Comment: I think it's hard to talk about because your snippet only has the one future, so there's nothing else to block that would effect anything. Perhaps an expanded example that illustrates something being blocked causing a problem would help? At the end of the day, it is an executor's job to block, because it is the synchronous blocking value that basically owns the execution of all of the tasks it manages. So if you use Tokio it's still blocking: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f96d5a5c2f1a258149b705cda7300846&version=stable

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. Please post an answer to the question if you have one. Your snippet still blocks the current thread, making it neither an answer to my question nor a solution to my problem.

Comment: My point is, without understanding why avoiding blocking the main thread is a goal of yours, it's not clear that any given answer would be the correct one for your usecase. If you're not blocking the main thread, are you planning to have a loop in your own code to constantly poll? What is driving this polling if you're doing that instead of blocking? If an future will take an unknown amount of time, it's not really efficient to spend the whole time checking to see if it is done, for instance.

Comment: *Please post an answer* to the question if you have one: this isn't an open discussion forum; my code and question are quite specific.

Comment: There are not realistically enough details to answer this in a meaningful way.

Comment: @loganfsmyth that is clearly false. Are there *any* concrete implementations of Executor? Obviously the answer is yes. How do I use done? My question is not unclear or unspecific in any way.

Comment: I feel like you're being  *incredibly unhelpful* here. Last time I posted a question here, I was told off for not being specific enough and asked to change it to be a code sample. This time, I post a code sample and I'm told oh, I don't understand 'why you're trying to do that', and I have to post a supporting essay to explain why I'm trying to write this code. :(

Comment: I promise I'm only trying to help answer your question. The point is, executors block. If they didn't, then they couldn't do their job efficiently. The only way to have one that doesn't block would be to implement your own essentially that blocked some of the time, but also allowed whatever other main thread stuff you want to happen to happen.

Comment: Fine, I don't care. Let it block. *how do I get an Executor?*

Comment: @Doug so did you take a look at the playground example from loganfsmyth with tokio?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't get one directly. They'd be created behind the scenes by APIs like tokio's `current_thread`, e.g. https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/hello-world/#spawning, or by the `core.run()` from my earlier example, or `.wait`, which creates one automatically: https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/src/futures/future/mod.rs.html#296

Comment: @Stefan https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-core#deprecation-notice "This crate is scheduled for deprecation in favor of tokio".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `tokio` and `futures` are designed as async primitives, not as a generic task system.

Which is to say, if you have multiple tasks you wish to dispatch asynchronously and 'fire and forget' them, use `thread::spawn`.

If you have multiple tasks you want to run *in a single thread*, then `Future` is the right primitive to use to block in that thread until a chain of futures are resolved.

In this case, my question didn't really make sense, because I thought that `Future` was supposed to represent something akin to `Task` in C#; that is, a dynamic dispatch to a threadpool for a task to be executes later, and the potential to chain actions to happen when that tasks resolved; with those tasks in turn to be executed in, potentially, different threads.

This is not the model that `futures` and `tokio` support.

However, I add here, just to irritate the nay-sayers, the answer to the actual question I asked:

The answer is that [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.1/tokio/index.html) implements a number of basic `Executor`'s, including one for arbitrary tasks.

see: https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.1/tokio/executor/current_thread/struct.TaskExecutor.html

specifically:
https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.1/tokio/executor/current_thread/index.html

You can use them like this:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;

use futures::Future;
use futures::future;
use futures::future::Executor;
use tokio::executor::current_thread;
use futures::sync::oneshot::{channel, Canceled};
use tokio::executor::current_thread::task_executor;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct RemoteReactor {
    channel: Sender<Box<Future<Item=(), Error=()> + Send + 'static>>
}

impl RemoteReactor {
    fn new() -> RemoteReactor {
        let (send, recv) = mpsc::channel::<Box<Future<Item=(), Error=()> + Send + 'static>>();
        let threadsafe_recv = Arc::new(Mutex::new(recv));
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let reader = threadsafe_recv.lock().unwrap();
            current_thread::run(|_| {
                loop {
                    let future = reader.recv().unwrap();
                    println!("Got a future!");
                    task_executor().execute(future).unwrap();
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
        return RemoteReactor {
            channel: send
        };
    }

    fn execute(&self, future: Box<Future<Item=(), Error=()> + Send + 'static>) {
        self.channel.send(future).unwrap();
    }
}

fn maybe_oneday() -> Box<Future<Item=i32, Error=Canceled> + Send + 'static> {
    let (s, r) = channel::<i32>();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        let _ = s.send(100);
    });
    return Box::new(r);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = maybe_oneday();
    let wrapper = Box::new(foo.then(|x| {
        match x {
            Ok(v) => {
                println!("GOT: {:?}", v);
                future::ok::<(), ()>(())
            }
            Err(y) => {
                println!("Err: {:?}", y);
                future::err::<(), ()>(())
            }
        }
    }));

    let reactor = RemoteReactor::new();
    reactor.execute(wrapper);

    println!("Waiting for future to resolve");
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));

    println!("All futures are probably resolved now");
}
```

NB. This code doesn't run on play.rust-lang.org (`error[E0463]: can't find crate for tokio`) for reasons I don't understand, but it does run rust 1.24:

```
rustc 1.24.0 (4d90ac38c 2018-02-12)

$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.1 secs
     Running `target\debug\hello_future.exe`
Waiting for future to resolve
Got a future!
GOT: 100
All futures are probably resolved now
```

Comment: It's good that you got your answer, but it's still not clear why this specific answer addressed your question, since `current_thread::run` will still block the main thread. Given your example code it's essentially identical to the `.wait` approach that you said you didn't want. Anyway, happy to end the discussion here.

Comment: The Playground takes the 100 most downloaded crates from crates.io (documented [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/help#features-crates)). Since `tokio` has only been recently published to something usable, it hasn't reached enough popularity to be brought into the Playground.